# What are the different ways of writing c++ pointers?

Tags: c++

Like the title above, I think I know my pointers. Yet, I'm not confident with them. I know of four ways to right pointers. They are:

```
*foo
&foo
->foo
.foo
```

The fourth one I don't know if it is right or not.

Comment: `know my pointers` I like this wording. you should read a basic book about C++.

Comment: Pls read up : https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html

Comment: Please clarify your question. Right now it unclear what is you asking. Some operators, which you have provided have nothing to do with pointers.

Answer (score 4):

None of those are "ways of writing pointers" or different pointer kinds.

- `*foo` is the pointer **dereference** operator
- `&foo` is the **address-of** operator
- `->` is the **dereference-and-access-member** operator (shorthand for `((*foo).)` - as a bonus this operator can be overloaded)
- `.` is the **member-access** operator

Different pointers in C++ (strictly, the C++ Standard Library), are:

- `Foo* ptr` - normal pointer
- `std::auto_ptr` - Deprecated. Calls the destructor when the pointer leaves scope.
- `std::shared_ptr` - Reference-counted pointer.
- `std::weak_ptr` - Allows use of a `shared_ptr`'s target without increasing the reference-count
- `std::unique_ptr` - Similar to `auto_ptr` but supports `std::move` and is the successor to `auto_ptr`.

The Boost library also defines:

- `scoped_ptr` - similar to `unique_ptr` but non-copyable and non-movable.
- `intrusive_ptr` - similar to `shared_ptr` except it allows the user to use their own reference-counting logic.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers can either point to the address of a variable (&foo), the value of an object or address (*foo) and from what I've been learning -> refers to an element of a structure.

For example let's say the variable a is located at memory location 1000 and contains the number 7.

&a would return 1000.
*(&a) would return 7.
And here's code of a structure and usage of the -> operator.

```
struct listNode {  /* self-referential structure */
char data;
struct listNode *nextPtr;
};
```

And here's usage of the -> operator referring to to the structure above:

```
while (currentPtr!=NULL) {
        if()
        printf("%c", currentPtr->data);
        currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;

    }
```

Comment: In general, you can't point to the address of a variable. That's two levels of indirection, and the address of a variable is an rvalue. (rvalues are things like the constant 4, you can't write `int* foo = &4` either) A pointer can _hold_ the address of a variable. The rest of the first sentence makes even less sense. `*foo` is the expression that refers to the object which lives at address `foo`. The _right_ of `->` refers to the member of a class, but the _left_ must be a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
*foo
```

Not a pointer. The act of *dereferencing* a pointer.

```
&foo
```

Not a pointer. An address.

```
->foo
```

Not a pointer. The act of dereferencing a pointer to a `struct` that contains a `foo` member.

```
.foo
```

Not a pointer in any way shape or form. The act of qualifying a `struct`-valued variable by the member name `foo`.